# How to access a variable set at run time with a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a variable I set at start up:

```
INFO = {:email => "foo@bar.com, :first_name => "foo", :last_name => "bar"}
```

Then I set `param[:type] = "info"`.

When I type `INFO` into the console I get this:

```
 => {:email=>"foo@bar.com", :first_name=>"foo", :last_name=>"bar"}
```

I would like to get that from typing `param[:type]` or "`info`".

Comment: awarded all responders! Thank you I was unaware of that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INFO` is a constant and, if it's declared in the global scope, you can retrieve it with:

```
Object.const_get "info".upcase 
Object.const_get param[:type].upcase
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was after :)